# Dynamically get Windows session ID for "PSExec -i"

Tags: bash, ssh, powershell

I am attempting to write a line of PowerShell to run a program remotely from a Linux machine to a Windows machine by means of pushing a PSExec command through SSH. If I manually query for the session ID and hard-code it in, it works, but the ID changes, so I want to dynamically pull it.

The current command is this:

```
ssh user@192.168.1.3 "psexec '\\\\192.168.1.3' -i Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {query session | grep user | grep -o [0-9]} -s $prgm"
```

Unfortunately, when I run the script, I receive the following error:

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
Starting Invoke-Command on 192.168.1.3....1.3...
PsExec could not start Invoke-Command on 192.168.1.3:
Binary file C:\Users\user\Desktop\Games\StepMania\Program\StepMania.exe matches
```

The filepath is due to code earlier in the script. It tries to match a script arg with a path on the Windows machine that it pulled from a text file. I can paste the whole script if you think it is required.

Comment: (1) If you have solved this (i.e., found a solution), please post an answer.  (2) It looks like you are trying to run two commands at once: PowerShell (`Invoke-Command`) and `"$prgm"`.  Do you know of any documentation that says that this is even possible?  (3) I realize that you aren’t even getting this far, but: When you say `grep user`, do you mean literally `g` `r` `e` `p` `⁠ ⁠` `u` `s` `e` `r`, or do you mean `grep <insert user name here>` (e.g., `grep TheMohawkNinja`)? … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) Your `grep -o [0-9]` will fail if the user name contains a digit, or if the session number is greater than 9 (if that’s possible).  Also, it’s not clear what will happen if the user isn’t logged in.  (What do you expect to happen?)  (5) Depending on what toolset you are using (Cygwin? WSL?), `grep -o [0-9]` might fail if there is a file whose name is a single digit.  Try ```grep -o '[0-9]'``` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this using PSExec, but getting the current pid of a started process is a simple as just doing this...

```
$process = Start-Process -FilePath "notepad" -PassThru
"Process Id is $($process.Id)"
```

Also, note that PowerShell has a default variable that holds the current process ID.

```
$pid
```

However, here is a response that says you can get the paid via psexec this way, let alone over SSH to what appears to be a Linux target. Note this is still talking Windows to Windows machines, vs you SSH session to what appears to be a Linux box.

[Get Process ID after starting psexec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43519345/get-process-id-after-starting-psexec)

```
& psexec -s -d -i $SessionID \\$PCname $Program $FilePath\$FileName |
   Select-String 'process ID (\d+)' | 
   ForEach-Object {$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}
```

Comment: (1) The question is about getting the Session ID.  pid ≠ Session ID.  (2) Your last command seems to assume that the user *already knows* the Session ID, which is the opposite of the situation that the question is describing.  (3) The question shows ``ssh … "psexec … query session …"``, and explicitly says that it’s trying to run a command on a Windows server by using `ssh` on a Linux client, so why are you talking about “a Linux target” and “you SSH session to what appears to be a Linux box”?

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh user@192.168.1.3 "psexec '\\\\192.168.1.3' powershell.exe -Command \"&{query session | grep user | grep -o [0-9]}\" -s $prgm"
```

Not quite sure what you're using the -s 'lowercase' param for on SSH... because it doesn't accept values in that parameter... Did you mean -S 'uppercase'?
[image: ssh command line]

In which case

```
ssh -S $prgm user@192.168.1.3 "psexec '\\\\192.168.1.3' powershell.exe -Command \"&{query session | grep user | grep -o [0-9]}\""
```

If you meant the -s switch of PsExec that too doesn't support any values being passed to the parameter...

Comment: Can you explain why you believe that this would make a difference? … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Because you can't run Invoke-Command without launching PowerShell. I thought that was obvious.

Comment: (1) Well, obviously, it wasn’t obvious to the author of the question.  Also, when you post a line of code that’s so long that barely half of it fits on the screen at once (so readers need to scroll horizontally) with ***no*** explanation, nothing is obvious.  (2) You’ve put ``$prgm`` inside the PowerShell command line, and I believe that that conflicts with what the OP wants.